# How can I filter noise in an audio file using FIR filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio

I just have a .wav file and I have added white Gaussian Noise to it using the code below:

```
%Reading the audio file
[originalAudio,Fs] = audioread('/Users/.../sound.wav');
%Adding white Guassian noise to the audio file
SNR = 20;
noisyAudio=awgn(originalAudio,SNR,'measured');
%sound(noisyAudio,Fs);
```

I want to remove the noise using FIR filter I tried the codes below for Convolution Filter.

```
 outputAudio = conv2(noisyAudio,noisyAudio,'same');
```

Is there a builtin function like this for doing the FIR filtering in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but if you want to do FIR filtering in matlab using built in functions, you can use `fir1` (or any of the other filter design functions) to generate filter coefficients, then `filter` to do the convolution. Digital filtering using LTI systems is by definition a convolution operation.

```
>> b = fir1(40, .5); % generate 40th order lowpass FIR filter at half the nyquist
>> filteredAudio = filter(b, 1, noisyAudio); % since this is FIR, the only feedback coefficient is 1 at y_n
```

But, this will not remove white noise. It will only attenuate frequencies (including those in the original audio signal) below half the nyquist frequency. Filtering is not the same thing as de-noising. However, convolving the noisy signal with itself isn't going to de-noise it either.

Comment: For a FIR filter `conv` can be used instead of `filter` (and it's probably more aligned with the OP's attempt)

Comment: The question mentions filtering and the post asked for built in Matlab functions, so I thought `filter` was the right way to go. However, as I point out, what the OP is really after is how to de-noise the signal and convolving it with the coefficients of an FIR filter will not do that. Matlab has no function like `denoise` that I am aware of (maybe one of the toolboxes?). Denoising is a vast problem in DSP research with many different approaches and applications.

Comment: My point was simply that, for a FIR filter, the `conv` function does the same as `filter`and is probably more familiar for the OP (based on their code). I don't agree that convolving with a FIR will not denoise. It _can_ actually denoise, with the appropriate filter coefficients (especially if the signal is band-limited or if some signal degradation is acceptable), although of course it will only remove _part_ of the noise. I agree that convolving the noisy signal with itself is not correct

Comment: I guess in some situations filters can denoise---albeit badly, but in the post the noise is broad spectrum. No LTI system will remove that without removing signal equally.